# Laravel 9: How much of memory usage is too much incase of Windows(using Xampp)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I installed [**barryvdh/laravel-debugbar**](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to check memory usage, which is showing more than **60MB**. Is that normal for a windows user? Or is that too high?

**More Statistics:**

> **Views:** 42
>
> **Livewire:** 4
>
> **Queries:** 6
>
> **Model:** 2
>
> **Cache:** 5

I tried reducing queries by eager loading, and even reduced models, later I started with caching too, but seems like it hardly reduced an MB.

Comment: That is not large, I would say this is quite good in fact

Comment: 60MB ain't large.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Wow, I thought it was too much. As a lot of blogs were having some screenshots where the users hardly had 4MB or so

Comment: @Charlie Can you suggest some range or so between which the memory usage must fall for Windows Xampp users?

Comment: xampp, apache, windows..... you are checking memory here out of all platforms?

Comment: There is no set value! You use what is required to run the code you write. Thats why there is a `max_memory` parameter. Thats there to stop us writing infinite loops that consume all the possibel memory. That value is normally set quite low by default. Normal running whould be possible in 256meg or less. Occasionally 512meg is required. But if you start blowing a 512meg limit, its normally a clue to make you look closer at your code to find  a reason, and normally a better way of processing your data. Arrays are normally the thing that blows memory limits

Comment: It depend on how and what kind query you exec, in php normally memory only release when request done. For me, less than 128MB all can be accept. And limit screenshots is because it's costs a lot of disk not cause memory, although that upload file will increaced request memory usage too, but not the main reason, because it'll release memory when request close. @Rajveer